# Generate the Sukodu Random Number

Tags: java, android, sudoku

Currently I am developing the Sudoku application. I need to generate a random number with given length. I know I could loop that times. but how to implement in android.

I directly included the sudoku string as

```
Public static final String  E1="020178030040302090100000006"+ "008603500300000004006709200"+"900000002080901060010436050";
```

But I want to generate this string randomly (as this 81 digit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of reference, I come a conclusion to find the Sudoku generation randomly

public class Sudokugeneration {

```
int[][] blockS = { { 4, 3, 5, 8, 7, 6, 1, 2, 9 },
                  { 8, 7, 6, 2, 1, 9, 3, 4, 5 },
                  { 2, 1, 9, 4, 3, 5, 7, 8, 6 },
                  { 5, 2, 3, 6, 4, 7, 8, 9, 1 },
                  { 9, 8, 1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7 },
                  { 6, 4, 7, 9, 8, 1, 2, 5, 3 },
                  { 7, 5, 4, 1, 6, 8, 9, 3, 2 },
                  { 3, 9, 2, 7, 5, 4, 6, 1, 8 },
                  { 1, 6, 8, 3, 9, 2, 5, 7, 4 } };

 Random R_num = new Random(); // random numbers to exchange rows
 Random Grid_R_num = new Random();// random numbers to exchange GRIDS
 Random R_exnum = new Random();
 Random H_Rnum = new Random();
 int carry[] = new int[9];
 int[][] blockh = new int[9][9];
 int[][] blockc = new int[9][9];

  int firstrow,secondrow,firstcol,secondcol,firstgrid,secondgrid;

 int gc = 0;
```

switching the rows
 randomly choosing one of the tow rows to be changed

for generate the puzzle

```
    int x = 10 + R_num.nextInt(10);

    for (int y = 0; y < x; y++) {
        for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
            // System.out.println("a="+a);

            if (a == 0) {
                firstrow = R_num.nextInt(3);
                secondrow = R_num.nextInt(3);
            }

            else if (a == 1) {
                firstrow = 3 + R_num.nextInt(3);
                secondrow = 3 + R_num.nextInt(3);
            }

            else if (a == 2) {
                firstrow = 6 + R_num.nextInt(3);
                secondrow = 6 + R_num.nextInt(3);
            }

           /* System.out.println("firstrow"+"="+firstrow);
            System.out.println("secondrow"+"="+secondrow);*/

            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                carry[i] = blockS[firstrow][i];
                blockS[firstrow][i] = blockS[secondrow][i];
                blockS[secondrow][i] = carry[i];
            }
        }
        // switching the rows complete

        // Switchicng the column
        for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
           /* System.out.println("a="+a);*/

            if (a == 0) {
                firstcol = R_num.nextInt(3);
                secondcol = R_num.nextInt(3);
            }

            else if (a == 1) {
                firstcol = 3 + R_num.nextInt(3);
                secondcol = 3 + R_num.nextInt(3);
            }

            else if (a == 2) {
                firstcol = 6 + R_num.nextInt(3);
                secondcol = 6 + R_num.nextInt(3);
            }

           /* System.out.println("firstcol"+"="+firstcol);
            System.out.println("secondcol"+"="+secondcol);*/

            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                carry[i] = blockS[i][firstcol];
                blockS[i][firstcol] = blockS[i][secondcol];
                blockS[i][secondcol] = carry[i];
            }
        }
    }
    // Switchicng the column complet

    // Switchicng the grids
    firstgrid = 1 + Grid_R_num.nextInt(3);
    secondgrid = 1 + Grid_R_num.nextInt(3);

   /* System.out.println("firstgrid"+"="+firstgrid);
    System.out.println("secondgrid"+"="+secondgrid);*/

    if ((firstgrid == 1 && secondgrid == 2) || (firstgrid == 2 && secondgrid == 1)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                carry[j] = blockS[i][j];
                blockS[i][j] = blockS[i + 3][j];
                blockS[i + 3][j] = carry[j];
            }
    } else if ((firstgrid == 2 && secondgrid == 3) || (firstgrid == 3 && secondgrid == 2)) {
        for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                carry[j] = blockS[i][j];
                blockS[i][j] = blockS[i + 3][j];
                blockS[i + 3][j] = carry[j];
            }
    } else if ((firstgrid == 1 && secondgrid == 3) || (firstgrid == 3 && secondgrid == 1)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                carry[j] = blockS[i][j];
                blockS[i][j] = blockS[i + 6][j];
                blockS[i + 6][j] = carry[j];
            }
    }
    // Swithing complete of tow grids

    // suffling the puzzle
    int firstnum, secondnum, shuffle;

    shuffle = 3 + R_num.nextInt(6);

    for (int k = 0; k < shuffle; k++) {
        firstnum = 1 + R_exnum.nextInt(9);
        secondnum = 1 + R_exnum.nextInt(9);


        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                if (blockS[i][j] == firstnum) {
                    blockS[i][j] = secondnum;
                    continue;
                }

                if (blockS[i][j] == secondnum)
                    blockS[i][j] = firstnum;
            }
    }
    return blockS;
}

// will save the complet puzzle
```

for save the puzzle

```
    if (gc == 0)
        blockc = generate();

    gc = 1;

    return blockc;
```

Answer (score 1):

`BigInteger` has a [random constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28int,%20java.util.Random%29):

```
private final int NUMBITS = 268;

public void test() {
    Random r = new Random();
    BigInteger b = new BigInteger(NUMBITS, r);
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

Comment: Thanks .It's working fine.but for Sudoku Puzzle how to check the repeat numbers in each rows and columns and eliminate the numbers

Comment: @PixelAswin - That is a different question. Post a new question, I am sure you will get help.